# CSS Toggle Switch Script - Help to change it to automatically resize?

Tags: css

I have some code that makes a neat toggle switch. The problem is I've been asked to make it resize automatically, but I can't figure out how without rewriting the entire code. Is there some simple fix I can make to this that would change it globally to let it resize automatically>?

For example, if I were to change the labels to "Affirmative" (on) or "Negative" (off), the text currently extends outside the boundaries of the span, but should widen instead.

This is the main css:

```
.toggle2 { min-width: 79px; height: 25px; display: inline-block; position: relative; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0; }
.toggle2 i {display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; text-align: center;  font: 13px/24px Arial !important; text-transform: uppercase;}
.toggle2 i:first-child {left: 0;background-color: #73B9FF;}
.toggle2 i:last-child {right: 0;background-color: #73B9FF;}
.toggle2.on i:first-child {-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;}
.toggle2.on i:last-child,
.toggle2.off i:first-child {text-indent: -9999px; width: 24px; height: 24px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; z-index: 1; background-color: #fff;}
.toggle2.off i:last-child {}
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LU5kp/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Remove `position:absolute` + `min-width: 79px` and add `padding: 0 10px 0 10px;` will give you a good start. [_fiddle demo_](http://jsfiddle.net/LU5kp/2/) ... then you need to fix your "round white buttons" into place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/slynagh/UmYkZ/

the CSS:

```
.toggle2 {

width:auto;
height: 24px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative; 
cursor: pointer; 
vertical-align: middle; 
padding: 0; 
}
.toggle2 i {
display: block; 
padding: 0 12px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px; 
border-radius: 12px; 
text-align: center;  
font: 13px/24px Arial !important; 
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.toggle2 i:first-child {
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; 
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
background-color: #73B9FF;
}
.toggle2 i:last-child {
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; 
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
background-color: #cc0000;
}
.toggle2.on i:first-child {

}


.toggle2.on i:last-child,
.toggle2.off i:first-child {
display:none;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
.toggle2.off i:last-child:before {
content: " ";
display:block;
position:absolute;
left:1px;
top:1px;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 22px; 
height: 22px;
-webkit-border-radius: 11px; 
-moz-border-radius: 11px; 
border-radius: 11px; 
z-index: 1; 
background-color: #fff;
}
.toggle2.on i:first-child:after {
content: " ";
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:-23px;
top:1px;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 22px; 
height: 22px;
-webkit-border-radius: 11px; 
-moz-border-radius: 11px; 
border-radius: 11px; 
z-index: 1; 
background-color: #fff;
}
```